# Display pages from specific page template

Tags: php, posts, css, page-template, code

Okay I have found the following code on line, which seems to be working and displaying all of the pages using the page_library_html.php template. This code only shows the title of them though. Can someone help me get the post content to show in  as well as the title in .

Thanks in advance

**Current code**

```
<?php
        $product_pages_args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page_library_html.php'
);

$product_pages = get_pages( $product_pages_args );
?>


<?php
foreach ( $product_pages as $product_page ) {
    echo '<div id="posts" class="flex_100"><div id="library_title"><a href="' . get_permalink( $product_page->ID ) . '">' . $product_page->post_title  . '</a>
    </div></div>';

}
?>
```

Comment: "Can you write code for me" is more of a request then a question, and one that has low chance of people replying to here. In addition your code doesn't seem to match your description. Please try to edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_post_field('post_content', $product_page->ID )` to get the content outside loop.

```
<?php
$product_pages_args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page_library_html.php'
);
$product_pages = get_pages( $product_pages_args );
?>

<?php
foreach ( $product_pages as $product_page ) {
    echo '<div id="posts" class="flex_100">';
    echo '<div id="library_title"><a href="' . get_permalink( $product_page->ID ) . '">' . $product_page->post_title  . '</a></div>';
    echo '<div class="page-content">' . get_post_field('post_content', $product_page->ID ) . '</div></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Subharanjan I've been looking for the answer for ages.